# Use of ? in return statement

Tags: java, return

In Java's String.class, I see this

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex){
   //if statements
   return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this:
     new String (offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

What is the '?' doing? While we're on the subject, can anyone explain whats happening with that 'new String' in the return statement? Is that some kind of conditional?

Comment: It's an inline if expression, `condition ? if true : if false`  http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: It is probably from a thought of "too little research" as I imagine this is a somewhat commonly asked question.  All the same, I don't think it is deserved, your English was clear (and you are relatively new, +1)

Comment: I did research it. "java using ?", "java return ?", "java using the character ?", etc, I get nothing. I had no idea what a ternary operator was so I couldn't search for that

Comment: If I type the following into google, the second result explains it all: `java "?" operator`. You only have to search properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [*ternary operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) and it is equivalent to:

```
if((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) {
  return this;
} else { 
  return new String (offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a ternary operator.

```
Cake mysteryCake = isChocolate() ? new Cake("Yummy Cake") : new Cake("Gross Cake");
```

Think of it as:

*If this condition is true, assign the first value, otherwise, assign the second.*

For a return statement, that becomes:

*If this condition is true, then return the first thing, otherwise return the second.*

Comment: Yeah, but it uses bad coding practice, as it is calling a static method for what should only be known after the Cake has been created!

Comment: +1 for a real-world example ;-). BTW consider removing braces around `isChocolate()`, might look better

Comment: Done; the braces around isChocolate() were a hold-over from my company's standards.

Comment: Oh, just noticed: `new Cake(isChocolate() ? "Yummy Cake", "Gross Cake")` is IMHO more readable (if ternary is ever readable ;-)).

Answer (score 2):

```
return boolValue ? a : b;
```

will return `a` if `boolValue` is true and `b` otherwise. It's a short form of `if` `else`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this:
 new String (offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
```

is the same of:

```
if ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) 
    return this;
else 
    return new String (offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` is the *ternary operator*: `a ? b : c` is equivalent to:

```
if (a) then b; else c;
```

> can anyone explain whats happening with that 'new String' in the return statement

The ternary operator is the conditional in this `return` statement, but `new String` is no sort of conditional, it is simply constructing a new `String`: depending on the conditional, this `return` statement returns either:

- `this`, or
- a new `String` object

Answer (score 0):

It is a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), used in many programming languages no just Java. It is quite useful to put everything in a single line basically it equals this:

```
if (endIndex == count && beginIndex == 0)
{
    return this;
}
else
{
   return new String (offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

New String is just a constructor.